# run time detection of processor type - atomic operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I am implementing some speed critical multithreaded code. I can avoid having some critical sections if I know for certain that some basic write operations are atomic. I just read an academic paper in which I saw the following:

"Writes of the basic types size t, int, float and pointer must be atomic. Writes by one thread must be seen by other threads in the same order. The IA-32 and Intel-64 CPU architectures, which are used in most modern standard computers, guarantee these assumptions."

What I would like to do is to be able to detect at run-time whether the processor is of a type in which these operations are atomic. - I'd like this to work for AMD processors too.

Comment: AMD processors support the IA32 CPU architecture, and they defined the AMD64 architecure from which Intel64 is derived.

Comment: Interesting. Like to know what paper that was and how you want to gurantee in the presence of compiler optimisations. If you are talking about assembley fine I believe that. Otherwise I find that hard to swallow.

Comment: Here's the paper:
www.cs.ualberta.ca/~mmueller/ps/enzenberger-mueller-acg12.pdf
I don't know what you mean by "how you want to gurantee in the presence of compiler optimisations".. who said I wanted to?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds redundant. The .EXE for this could simply be `int main() { return true; }`. Either it runs, and the answer is correct, or the OS is unable to run the .EXE at all becaus the processor type doesn't match the .EXE type.

Comment: But I could make two different versions - a slow one with critical sections and a fast one without. I would like to include a test in the fast one to be able to gracefully exit rather than crash or produce wrong answers.

Comment: No need to. Just use `InterlockedIncrementAcquire`, that uses the fastest algorithm everywhere. Even on Itanic.

Comment: InterlockedIncrementAcquire is Win32 specific.

Comment: No it isn't. Win32, Win64-x64 and Win64-IPF. See also comment on `InterlockedIncrement`. It's Windows-specific though, but check the tags: Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is off topic but if you are planning to write lock free code you should definatly read this first [Lock-Free Code: A False Sense of Security](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/210600279) by Herb Sutter

Quote from the article:

> Lock-free code has two major
>   drawbacks. First, it's not broadly
>   useful for solving typical
>   problems—lots of basic data
>   structures, even doubly linked lists,
>   still have no known lock-free
>   implementations. Coming up with a new
>   or improved lock-free data structure
>   will still earn you at least a
>   published paper in a refereed journal,
>   and sometimes a degree.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting into these CPU/platform specific issues you could consider:

Waiting for std::atomic in the c++0x standard (already available for GCC)

*or*

Using [Intel TBB](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-tbb/)

*or*

Using the [ACE_Atomic_Op](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.6.6/html/ace/a00029.html)